# ng-token-auth and devise token auth confirmation redirect url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I know this has been asked a lot and I've seen many solutions that don't seem to apply to my issue, so I apologize if I missed something.

When sending a confirmation email using Devise's views with ng-token-auth and devise-token-auth the confirmation email link does not have a `redirect_url` and will show me an error page when clicking on it, however the confirmation api call succeeds.

in `ng-token-auth` config I've set:
`confirmationSuccessUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/#!/login'`

in `devise_token_auth.rb` I've also set:
`config.default_confirm_success_url = 'http://localhost:8000/#!/login'`

I have also tried overriding the `ConfirmationsController` as suggested in many other solutions, all to no avail.

I've got a temporary work around by editing the devise view `confirmation_instructions.html.erb` by adding `redirect_url` to the `confrimation_url` call:

`confirmation_url(@resource, redirect_url:'http://localhost:8000/#!/login', confirmation_token: @token)`

Thanks in advance, and please let me know if I can provide any additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the link is always sending an `HTTP 406` so the object always has an error, but not always a message. For the time being, I've implemented (an ugly) solution by overriding the confirmations controller as such:

```
 def show
    self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])
    yield resource if block_given?

    if resource.errors.messages.empty?
        set_flash_message!(:notice, :confirmed)
        #respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource) }
        if signed_in?(resource_name)
            #signed_in_root_path(root_path)
            redirect_to root_path + '#!/users/' + resource.id.to_s
        else
            redirect_to root_path + '#!/login'
        end
    else
        respond_with_navigational(resource.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity){ render :new }
    end
end
```

This will, at worst, redirect to the login page. Since the confirmations api call is actually working, the user can sign in. If it fails, I can show a flash message indicating they should try to resend the confirmation email.

If anyone knows of a better solution or what I'm doing wrong to cause the `HTTP 406` please let me know!